# Pandas Series to Excel

Tags: python, pandas

The pandas.Series object [does have many `to_*` functions](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.Series.html), yet it lacks a `to_excel` function. Is there an easier/better way to accomplish the export in line 3 of this snippet? It feels clunky to first convert the Series to a DataFrame simply for a simple I/O:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series([1,3,5,np.nan,6,8])
pd.DataFrame(s).to_excel('s.xlsx', 's')
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can either:

#### 1. construct a `DataFrame` from the start,

in which case you've already answered your own question.

#### 2. Use `Series.to_frame()`

```
s.to_frame(name='column_name').to_excel('xlfile.xlsx', sheet_name='s')
```

Comment: Ok, so the answer is actually "nope". But the `to_frame` queues nice, saves me one line for a manual s.name change and looks less like an ugly typecast (which the pd.DataFrame looks like to me) in my context.

Comment: This might be a good first pull request over on github if you're interested, though I'm not sure how common writing a single column to an Excel table is.

Comment: If it happens to me a second time I will consider doing that; it just happened to me from summing over a DataFrame.

Comment: FYI, there's also a `DataFrame.squeeze()` method that will turn a single column `DataFrame` into a `Series`.

Comment: Did anyone created that issue on github? I couldn't find it.

Comment: I opened an issue about this several times ago https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8825

Answer (score 3):

### New in 0.20: Series.to_excel()

Beginning with pandas version 0.20, Series now supports `to_excel` directly (see [PR #8825](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8825) for details):

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series([0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16], name='a_series')
s.to_excel('foo.xlsx')
```

Contents of file foo.xlsx:

```
  |  A | B         | 
--+----+-----------+---------------------
1 |    | a_series  | 
2 |  0 | 0         | 
3 |  1 | 1         | 
4 |  2 | 2         | 
5 |  3 | 4         | 
6 |  4 | 8         | 
7 |  5 | 16        | 
-.           ,---------------------------
  \ Sheet 1 /  \ Sheet 2 / \ Sheet 3 /
```

Comment: Is there a way to change the writing of Series from vertical to horizontal, so that the index is used as columns?

Comment: @KrzysztofSłowiński not directly, only through `s.to_frame().T.to_excel(...)`, using DataFrame's transpose operation.