# How to insert a dictionary into an existing excel file with pandas

Tags: python, database, excel, pandas

I have an existing excel file in documents which I open as a data frame with `df = pd.read_excel(filename, index_col ='respID')` and then I read and treat as a normal data frame.

I process some data and I then have two dictionaries whose key values are the same as the index values of the data frame.

I'm looking to insert these dictionaries into the excel file after a specific column. How would I go about doing this. Would it be better if they were just series?

I've seen solutions
[How to write to an existing excel file without overwriting data (using pandas)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20219254/how-to-write-to-an-existing-excel-file-without-overwriting-data-using-pandas) and [Pandas Series to Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23365466/pandas-series-to-excel) but I don't think either answers my question totally.

Worst comes to worst I can add the dictionaries to the data frame where I want them and just overwrite the entire excel file or write a new one and replace it but that seems inelegant.

Thank you.

Comment: You can make a dictionary a `pd.Series` with `pd.Series(mydict)`

Comment: Right and if I added that series to the data frame then would it automatically update the excel file? I don't think so because I believe the data frame has just read the excel file they're not interconnected although I could be wrong.

Comment: Correct, pandas maintains no connections to Excel. You need to export back into Excel format.