# Save Dictionary of Multiple Series to Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe with 101 columns and I want to look at the distribution of each variable in my DataFrame. Using Pandas value_counts I have created a dictionary of several series with multiple lengths.  Each series has its own key.

First I do:

```
    out={}
    for c in df.columns:
    out[c]=df[c].value_counts(dropna=False).fillna(0)
```

So, out is a dictionary with size 101. Within out is a list of series with various sizes.

```
Key     |  Type  | Size |  Value
Key1      Series   (12,)   class 'pandas.core.series.Series'
Key2      Series   (7,)    class 'pandas.core.series.Series'
Key3      Series   (24,)   class 'pandas.core.series.Series'
.
.
.
Key101
```

Each Key is unique. I want to save each of these series to an Excel file. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23366074/7045049) is close and will work for the first key in the loop, but it won't continue on to the next key in the dictionary.  This is what I have now:

```
for key in out.keys():
    s=out[key]
    name=key[:30]
    s.to_excel('xlfile.xlsx', sheet_name=name)
```

I only keep the first 30 characters because that is the limit in excel for a sheet name. I don't necessary need them to have their own sheet, I would rather them all be saved to a single sheet by column, but this is the closest I can get to saving them. Obviously a newbie, so if there is a better approach to my fundamental question, that would be awesome too.

I'm open to any suggestions, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need [ExcelWriter](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#writing-excel-files-to-disk):

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('xlfile.xlsx')
for key in out.keys():
    out[key].to_excel(writer, sheet_name=key[:30])
writer.save()
```

Or if is not necessary create `dict`, write it in first loop (also advantage is same order of `sheet names` as `columns` of `DataFrame`):

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('xlfile.xlsx')
for c in df.columns:
    df[c].value_counts(dropna=False).fillna(0).to_excel(writer, sheet_name=c[:30])
writer.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an excel writer and pass that into the loop i.e.

```
>>> writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
>>> df1.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
>>> df2.to_excel(writer,'Sheet2')
>>> writer.save()
```

Refer [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) for more